# React Native: Background image loads as the last component, albeit it's added first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my exact code:

```
    <Image source={require('./images/person.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Greeting name='Rexxar' />
            <Greeting name='Jaina' />
            <Greeting name='Valeera' />
            <Bananas />
            <Blinking />
        </View>
    </Image>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'contain', 
    width : null,
    height : null
  }
}
```

When I try to add `person.png` as a background image, it works fine, but the images loads as the last component, which is not a good behavior, since I want the background image to show before everything else. Is there a way to avoid this, or may be I'm doing it wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by handling the onLoad event of the Image.

```
<Image 
  source={require('./images/person.png')} 
  style={styles.backgroundImage}
  onLoad={e => this.setState({ viewVisible: true })}
>
  {this.state.viewVisible ?
     <View style={styles.container}>
        <Greeting name='Rexxar' />
        <Greeting name='Jaina' />
        <Greeting name='Valeera' />
        <Bananas />
        <Blinking />
     </View>
  : null}
</Image>
```

Comment: This is a good approach, yet, it becomes cumbersome with large number of components in the project, is there another more native way that allows us to load components/objects in the order they are added with?

Comment: Also, there is a problem with this solution, I just tried it: The background image loads the first, but disappears, and the rest of the components show up, then the background image shows again!! What is that? Why did it disappear and show up again?